# How can I find and edit a line in a text file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, random, line, edit

I have a text file with multiple of lines. Each line contains a known word and an unknown number. I want to make a batch file which searches for a specific line (with a known word) and replaces the random number with a number with is entered by the user.
I already used [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net) but I don't know the part with the unknown number.

Comment: *`I already used FART`* Show us your code and how are you using it... `Fart` accept wildcards...

Comment: I suggest you to use PowerShell instead BATCH.